# suggest an alternate to getimagesize() in JS or PHP

Tags: php, javascript

For reasons unknown to mankind, I have been forbidden to use `getimagesize()`, is there any better alternate to `getimagesize()` which can handle timeouts if I open a remote image? I am also looking at JS options

Server guys tell me `allow_url_fopen` is turned off. I didn't check it :( My fault.

Comment: I am more interested in image dimensions in pixels by pixels, height width

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A JS solution would be to load the image into some hidden `<img>`-tag, attach a JS callback on the `onload` event, check the image size in there, do the appropriate resizing and move the `<img>`-node into the correct place in your DOM tree.

Comment: yes thats what I will be doing. Thanks, I shall accept your answer to close this question. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Imagick](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php)? It has many advanced functions as well as [getImageSize()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagick-getimagesize.php). Documentation sucks, but in this case, there are some comments that demonstrate it's use.

None of these functions will work with remote files (as far as I know) so you should download them and than work with them.

Comment: well, all I need to do is display a remote image and if the image size is larger then a given constrain, resize the image using CSS, IMHO, using Imagick will be an overhead on server side. I shall be using JS to handle this.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exif-read-data.php

Comment: In my scenario none of exif and getimagesize functions work, they all return false, I have contacted the server guys :-)